# How to tell Validator to call another Rule checker

Tags: validation, cakephp-3.0

I have this table :

```
+-----+-------------+------------+--------------+---------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------+----------+------------+--------+---------+
| id  | rule_number | profile_id | dest_ip_type | dest_ip | dest_ip_mask | dest_iprange_first | dest_iprange_last | dest_fqdn   | protocol | dest_ports | target | enabled |
+-----+-------------+------------+--------------+---------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------+----------+------------+--------+---------+
| 187 |           3 |         56 | net          | 8.8.8.8 |           32 |                    |                   |             | both     | 53         | ACCEPT |       1 |
| 188 |           2 |         56 | range        |         |            0 | 192.168.1.20       | 192.168.1.250     |             | both     | 53         | ACCEPT |       1 |
| 189 |           1 |         56 | fqdn         |         |            0 |                    |                   | my.host.com | both     | 80         | ACCEPT |       1 |
+-----+-------------+------------+--------------+---------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------+----------+------------+--------+---------+
```

From my controller I call Validator depending on "dest_ip_type" :

```
public function validationNet(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator = $this->validationDefault($validator);

    $validator
        ->notEmpty('dest_ip', __('IP is required'))
        ->notEmpty('dest_ip_mask', __('Mask is required'))
        ->allowEmpty('dest_iprange_first')
        ->allowEmpty('dest_iprange_last')
        ->allowEmpty('dest_fqdn');

    $validator
        ->add('dest_ip', 'notEmpty', [
            'rule' => ['ip', 'ipv4'],
            'message' => __('Invalid IP Address')
        ]);

    return $validator;

}

public function validationIprange(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator = $this->validationDefault($validator);

    $validator
        ->notEmpty('dest_iprange_first', __('IP is required'))
        ->notEmpty('dest_iprange_last', __('IP is required'))
        ->allowEmpty('dest_ip')
        ->allowEmpty('dest_ip_mask')
        ->allowEmpty('dest_fqdn');

    $validator
        ->add('dest_iprange_first', 'ipv4', [
            'rule' => ['ip', 'ipv4'],
            'message' => __('Invalid IP Address')
        ]);

    $validator
        ->add('dest_iprange_last', 'ipv4', [
            'rule' => ['ip', 'ipv4'],
            'message' => __('Invalid IP Address')
        ]);

    return $validator;
}

public function validationFqdn(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator = $this->validationDefault($validator);

    $validator
        ->notEmpty('dest_fqdn')
        ->allowEmpty('dest_iprange_first')
        ->allowEmpty('dest_iprange_last')
        ->allowEmpty('dest_ip')
        ->allowEmpty('dest_ip_mask');

    $validator
    ->add('dest_fqdn', 'notEmpty', [
        // Regex for FQDN
        'rule' => ['custom', "/(?=^.{4,253}$)(^((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}$)/i"],
        'message' => __('Invalid Hostname')
    ]);

    return $validator;
}
```

I created 3 RulesChecker bellow to check unique differently, but How can I tell Validator or Controller to not call default "buildRules" function but force to call alternative buildRules ?

```
public function buildNetRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['profile_id'], 'Profiles'));
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['profile_id', 'dest_ip', 'protocol', 'dest_ports']));

    return $rules;
}

public function buildRangeRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['profile_id'], 'Profiles'));
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['profile_id', 'dest_iprange_first', 'dest_iprange_last', 'protocol', 'dest_ports']));

    return $rules;
}

public function buildFqdnRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['profile_id'], 'Profiles'));
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['profile_id', 'dest_fqdn', 'protocol', 'dest_ports']));

    return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by my self. buildRules is able to check different isunique rules inside de same function. Maybe buildRules don't check isUnique rules on values that are Empty or null...

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['profile_id'], 'Profiles'));
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['profile_id', 'dest_ip', 'protocol', 'dest_ports']));
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['profile_id', 'dest_iprange_first', 'dest_iprange_last', 'protocol', 'dest_ports']));
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['profile_id', 'dest_fqdn', 'protocol', 'dest_ports']));

    return $rules;
}
```